# Get the current record of a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a recordset of objects `employees`, I can move using the `.MoveX`'s methods. However, I would like to know how I can create an object `employee` with the current record of the recordset `employees`.

```
Dim employees As DAO.Recordset
Dim employee  As DAO.Recordset

Set employees = database.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES", dbOpenDynaset)
Do While Not employees.EOF

    // Some magic function 'GetCurrentRecord'
    employee = employees.GetCurrentRecord
    // I can do stuff with 'employee'
    MsgBox "Name: " & employee.Fields("Name").Value

    employees.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

From example not clear why you need `employee` object, you can use `employees` recordset for accessing data in current record in each loop step, but if you want, for instance, to find some recordset rows in loop and then access those rows, you can use `Bookmark` recordset property for storing/restoring current recordset position.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention yourself, the obvious method is to create a new recordset with that single current record:

```
Dim employees As DAO.Recordset
Dim employee  As DAO.Recordset

Set employees = database.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES", dbOpenDynaset)
Do While Not employees.EOF
    ' Specify condition when to extract the current record.
    If SomeCondition = True Then
        employees.Filter = "Id = " & employees!Id.Value & ""
        Set employee = employees.OpenRecordset
        Exit Do
    End If   
    employees.MoveNext
Loop

If Not employee Is Nothing Then
    ' I can do stuff with 'employee'
    MsgBox "Name: " & employee.Fields("Name").Value
End If
```

Comment: I often see that moving to the first record(`employees.movefirst`) is considered good practice; would it be needed here? if not then why?

Comment: The recordset will always open on the first record - if any. If no records, EOF will be True.